# How to safely measure VCEO or VCES of a transistor?

Tags: transistors, npn, pnp

As an example, NPN Silicon Power Transistor TIP31 VCEO (Collector-Emitter Voltage) is rated at 40Vdc Maximum. I have many unknown transistors for which I would need to measure the VCEO. Many are power transistors, many are low power.
Is there a safe way to measure VCEO (or VCES) of a transistor? (avoiding to fry the unit)

Comment: Limit the current. Use 10Kohm resistor as starting value. Examine the curves on a real curve-tracer. If you see heating, the curves will be changing second by second, and you are putting the device at risk. In that case, increase the resistor. You'll likely see lots of looping in the curves, because of phase-shifts (R*C delays); live with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple way to measure it. You'll need a voltage supply rail that is high enough to reach the voltages you want to test, of course. (\$V_\text{SUPPLY}\gt V_\text{CEO}\$.) If this is a lab supply that allows you to set a current limit, use that feature. If you don't have a current limiting feature to access, then you will need to fabricate something (not hard, but again if you are using BJTs for this you need to be sure *their* \$V_\text{CEO}\$ is large enough.)

Just set the desired current and feed the current source to the collector of the BJT. Leave the base open, of course. Hook the emitter to the other side of the power supply. Attach a voltmeter across the emitter and collector and measure the voltage there.

The current source (or sink, depending) should be set to a value you feel comfortable with considering the BJT. Make sure that you test this current source/sink with a few different resistors to be sure that it is doing what you expect and yielding a value you want -- before applying it to your transistor.

That's about it. Don't test too long. Just long enough to get your measurement. See [Vishay's Measurement Techniques](https://www.vishay.com/docs/80061/80061.pdf) for an example (Figure 3.)

Answer (score 2):

The  VCEO is similar to operating a Zener 
12 Watts is considered safe for this 40W device.  ( 0.12A @100V)

Simply use a sufficiently high R value to measure V with a DMM.
[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVAIoo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Anecdotal

My tube TV in late 70's needed a 160V regulated voltage (HSweep) so I looked up the Vceo of my spare parts and found one in that range and it worked same as a Zener. Cheap and quick fix.

Comment: Thanks Tony Stewart, just a little Anectotal from one of my experiments. I tried that method one on a big Power rectifier able to handle some 100 Amps (no kinding) the diode did not come with aa specsheet so I started to apply a DC voltage in series with a 10K resistor (reverse voltage) wanted to check the max reverse voltage of that device. When I reached near 40Vdc the unit became totally short. I fried my $20 diode. I did not repeat the test with the 3 others. Now I know that I should not apply more then 30V or so. I never found the technical reason the that fatal accident.

Comment: Some avalanche negative resistance failure modes can exist if the space charge layer is non-uniform and it arcs with the equivalent of 10kV/mm or 10/um. Well I've seen a lot of dead hockey puck diodes that others burnt out in the mid-70's from SOA transients too.

Answer (score 1):

A curve tracer would do it, but if you had a Tektronix curve tracer you wouldn't be asking (photo from [here](http://w140.com/tekwiki/wiki/File:Tek-371a-small.jpg)).

[image]

If you have a suitable power supply you can manually trace curves by putting a relatively **high value resistor** in series with the transistor and **slowly** increasing the voltage until you start to observe breakdown (don't put too much current through the transistor or it may be damaged).

If you guess right and don't put too much current for the type of transistor there will be no damage (assuming a BJT- it will destroy a MOSFET gate if there is no internal gate protection).

Test some known transistors to get an idea of the safety margins manufacturers use.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing puffs the final smoke out as long as you do not burn anything. You can well exceed some breakthrough limit voltage. Only keep the dissipated energy small enough.

That's not true if you test insulators, because the area of the breakthrough isn't under your control - very small energy can cause irreversible heating if it happens in area small enough. But transistors and diodes generally do not get destroyed, if you keep the dissipated power low enough.

If you are lucky enough to have an oscilloscope, make an XY plotting circuit which shows Ic vs Uce when a fast and sparse ramp or sine pulse is applied.

Oscilloscope is not a must. As well you can construct a circuit which applies growing Vce. A current sense circuit switches Vce off as soon as the pretermined Ic is reached. A hold circuit saves the highest Vce into a capcitor and you can read it from a DVM.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a note of caution as there is a lower Vceo voltage that occurs when the transistors is conducting and the base current is suddenly turned off. This is **less** than the Vceo voltage measured in the other answers here. You can think of regular Vceo as the 'strike' voltage for an arc lamp and the lower minimum 'Vceo sustain' as the voltage that will keep the arc going.
For example, the Motorola datasheet for the 2N3866A shows only 'Vceo(sus)' - 30V in this case - but this value is labelled as plain 'Vceo' on other datasheets. If you measure the Vceo 'strike' voltage this is around 90V or nearly 3 times higher than the Vceo (sus), so you need to take care before relying on the measured 'strike' voltage.
When measuring Vceo(sus) you need to look out for heat as the transistor will still be conducting with the test voltage applied, eg 5mA at 100V = 0.5W